# nodejs post method not working

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to nodejs. Here post method is not working. So i need help..

below is my .js file.

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.listen(1465, function() {
  console.log('listeninggg at port 1465');
});
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index4.html");
});
app.post('/hello', function(req, res) {
  res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.user_name + '".');
});
```

below is my html file.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form action="localhost:1465/hello" method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="user_name"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: i didnt find any errors

Comment: Use this `action="//localhost:1465/hello"` (or remove `action` entirely, since the URL is identical) You should also tell us which tutorial you're following, because there are *way* better ones out there.

Comment: It worked.Thank you.i referring codedamm tutorial and tutorialspoint.if you know some better tutorials, u can suggest.